# Is it possible to run Python code on an Apache server

Tags: php, python, pygame

What kind of server configurations would I need to do in order to run a Python + Pygame code on a website.

Is php able to call and execute the python on server side? Do I need to install python on the server? I believe python is installed, but do I need to install the pygame library? What if I compile my code, will I need to install pygame on the server after that?

Can some one provide me a general list of things I will need to complete in order to make this happen?

My case:

I would like to put a game I made with Python on a website. I see how the python can run on the server no problem, but how can I ensure the client be able to play the game on their browser?

Comment: It's certainly possible to run some Python code that uses Pygame under Apache, but the result is almost certainly not what you'd expect: as soon as someone visits the page, it will try to connect to an X server on the server running Apache, which, if it doesn't fail, might open the game to be played on the server rather than letting the client play it.

Comment: With that said if you gave some more information about your use case we might be able to help you more.

Comment: @icktoofay Yes, I've added my case. I would like the client to be able to play a game that I made. How can I connect what the python code with the browser? Can I made the player download the code and run from the browser with a python plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a Python plugin somewhere, but I don't know of it and I can't imagine it's very popular. Your best bet would be to use [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/), previously called Pyjamas, which can translate Python to JavaScript. It doesn't support Pygame, but you might be able to write a Pygame-compatible module using the browser's `canvas` support. It's not a solution that you can just drop in and go, but I don't think there is one.

Answer (score 2):

Web Browser can display/run HTML+JavaScript+SVG+(HTML)Canvas or (Adobe) Flash. You can't use PyGame to create game running on page. PyGame doesn't generate HTML+JavaScript or Flash

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a mod like mod_php... The extension of files are
.psp
Python server pages

Comment: You'd more commonly use either CGI scripts, FastCGI, or uWSGI. That said, neither your solution nor any of the other things I mentioned in this comment would solve the Pygame problem.